# What is the replacement for DirectProcessor

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Kafka publisher which publishes the data using `DirectProcessor` class of Project Reactor. But as per the [official document](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/DirectProcessor.html), `DirectProcessor` is getting deprecated and will be removed in version 3.5.

Current implementation

```
@Bean
public DirectProcessor<RequestDTO> publisher(){
   return DirectProcessor.create();
}

@Bean
public FluxSink<RequestDTO> sink(DirectProcessor<RequestDTO> publisher){
   return publisher.sink();
}
```

And here is the Supplier which supplies the data to the Kafka binder using `DirectProcessor` bean configured above.

```
@Autowired
private DirectProcessor<RequestDTO> source;

@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<RequestDTO>> supplier(){
     return () -> Flux.from(source);
};
```

I tried to use the recommended way using Sinks to replace DirectProcessor.

```
@Bean
public Sinks.Many<RequestDTO> newSink() {
   return Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
}
```

```
@Autowired
private Sinks.Many<RequestDTO> newSink;

@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Sinks.Many<RequestDTO>>> supplier(){
    return () -> Flux.from(newSink);
};
```

But the application start failed with this exception

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'supplierInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowBuilder org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows.from(java.util.function.Supplier)'
```

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, we have `StreamBridge` component for that - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources.
Meanwhile, feel free to raise an issue (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues) and we'll take a look since what you're describing should work as well.

Comment: Raised an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2242